# What are the downsides of using plain html <script> tag in nextjs?

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering, flicker

I am new to nextjs and I'm trying to avoid the "flickering/flashing" effect when reloading my website when setting the dark theme.

On my react app, I'm used to read the localStorage directly in a  tag embedded in the root index.html and setting a dark background. Here is the code:

```html
  <body style="height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px">
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script>
const theme = localStorage.getItem('theme');
if (localStorage.getItem('theme') === 'dark') {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#141517';
  document.body.style.color = '#fff';
} else {
  document.body.classList.add('default-theme');
}
    </script>
  </body>
```

When it comes to nextJs, I've heard about Server Side Rendering (SSR) and I'd like to avoid breaking optimizations.

I get rid of the flash effect by adding a plain `<script>` inside the  in the _app.tsx :

```html
    <>
      <Head>
        <script src="/theme.js" />
      </Head>
      <GlobalStyle />
      <>
      <Providers>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Providers>
    </>
    </>
```

But the development server complains:

`Do not add <script> tags using next/head (see <script> tag with src="/theme.js"). Use next/script instead. See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-script-tags-in-head-component`

The doc says to use a `<Script>` component, I've tried this:

```html
    <>
      <Head>
      </Head>
      <GlobalStyle />
      <Script src="/theme.js" strategy="beforeInteractive" />
      <>
      <Providers>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Providers>
    </>
    </>
```

But the flash effect comes back.

Here is my theme.js file:

```js
;(function initTheme() {
    var theme = localStorage.getItem('nextColorMode') || 'light'
    if (theme === 'dark') {
      document.querySelector('html').style.background = 'black'
    }
  })()
```

Should I continue with the warning given in the first solution ?